# MyBatis 3.0.5 and mappers loading problem

Tags: java, ibatis, mybatis

I'm using MyBatis 3.0.5 and I have problems about the loading of mappers as resources. I'm on Windows 7 64, I use Eclipse Indigo 64bit and jdk7 64. MyBatis is initialized in a Grizzly Web Container (where are implemented rest services with jersey framework) standalone instance.

```
<mappers>
        <mapper
            url="file:///C:/Users/andrea/workspace/soap2rest/src/main/java/com/izs/mybatis/FormMapper.xml" />
        <mapper resource="src/main/java/com/izs/mybatis/FormMapper.xml" />
    </mappers>
```

I have the same mappers only for testing, the first is loaded, the second doesn't work. Errors:

```
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error building SqlSession.
### The error may exist in src/main/java/com/izs/mybatis/FormMapper.xml
### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: java.io.IOException: Could not find resource src/main/java/com/izs/mybatis/FormMapper.xml
    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:8)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.build(SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.java:32)
    at com.izs.Main.initMyBatis(Main.java:114)
    at com.izs.Main.main(Main.java:80)
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: java.io.IOException: Could not find resource src/main/java/com/izs/mybatis/FormMapper.xml
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.parseConfiguration(XMLConfigBuilder.java:85)
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.parse(XMLConfigBuilder.java:69)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.build(SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.java:30)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not find resource src/main/java/com/izs/mybatis/FormMapper.xml
    at org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources.getResourceAsStream(Resources.java:89)
    at org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources.getResourceAsStream(Resources.java:76)
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.mapperElement(XMLConfigBuilder.java:253)
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.parseConfiguration(XMLConfigBuilder.java:83)
    ... 4 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.izs.Main.initMyBatis(Main.java:122)
    at com.izs.Main.main(Main.java:80)
```

Sorry for my english.

**SOLUTION:** 
Maven projects want resources into src/main/resources and src/test/resources for tests. So the solution is to put the xml mappers into these folders.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use absolute paths. It makes your code unportable and unused on another environment. Just relative acceptable. For your example, I guess you can use the following relative path:

```
<mapper resource="com/izs/mybatis/FormMapper.xml" />
```

Comment: I would to use resources for your same reasons but they don't work... also using your suggestion.

Comment: Could you please describe what folder structure do you have?

Comment: thx for helping, I have a Maven project with the classpath src/main/java and the packages:
src/main/java/com/izs within Main.java
src/main/java/com/izs/mybatis within FormMapper.xml

Comment: you have to put you xml on the resource folder as `src/main/resource/com/izs/mybatis` that's where the `<mapper resource=` try to find the resources. And then use the suggestion on the @BrownFurSeal answer.