# why xml files in eclipse project's source directory is not copied to target/classes directory?

Tags: xml, eclipse, maven, buildpath, eclipse-project-file

this issue is not the same as [MyBatis 3.0.5 and mappers loading problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557111/mybatis-3-0-5-and-mappers-loading-problem) and [How to suppress Maven "Unable to find resource" messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878309/how-to-suppress-maven-unable-to-find-resource-messages)

i have xml files in org.org.wpse.db.config.db.config package, but why i cannot find these xml files in target/classes/org/wpse/db/config/ directory even after i run mvn compile.

this error leads to the following faillure when i use mybatis:

```
Could not find resource
```

the issue which lead to this error is that the .xml files are not copied to the build dir, even i when i used mvn compile explicitly

Comment: Where is this package - in `src/main/java` or `src/main/resources`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maven is by default looking for resource files i.e. *.xml, *.properties and etc. in `src/main/resources` directory. It is recommended to put your resource files under here.

However, nothing prevent you from putting resource files somewhere else, for instance, `src/main/java/org/wpse/db/config/`, as some people prefer to put resource files along with class file under special package, you just need a little more configuration in pom.xml:

```
<build>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <!-- This include everything else under src/main/java directory -->
      <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </resource>
  </resources>

  ... ...
</build>
```

---

**Related question:** [how to customize maven to generate the .classpath that i want?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444772/how-to-customize-maven-to-generate-the-classpath-that-i-want)

By default configuration, when running `mvn eclipse:eclipse` it generates following .classpath file:

```
<classpath>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java" including="**/*.java"/>
  ... ...
</classpath>
... ...
```

When importing into Eclipse, it gives you following classpath (what you don't want):

[image]

Using the pom configuration above, when running 'mvn eclipse:eclipse' it generates following .classpath file:

```
<classpath>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java"/>
  ... ...
</classpath>
... ...
```

When importing into Eclipse, it gives you follwing classpath (what you want):

[image]