# how to customize maven to generate the .classpath that i want?

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3, m2eclipse

using the following command

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

i can get a .classpath with the line such as:

```
 <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java" including="**/*.java"/>
```

but this is not the configuration i want, i want it to be

```
 <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java" including="**/*.*"/>
```

that means it should be **including="**/*.*"** and not including="**/*.**jave**"

why i should do in order to  customize maven to generate the .classpath that i want?

Comment: Just curious. Why would you want to include non-java files in src?

Comment: I suppose this question is related another one you previously asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444683/why-xml-files-in-eclipse-projects-source-directory-is-not-copied-to-target-clas/12446666#12446666), see my answer in the other question.

Comment: @Raghuram it is configuration files, which is needed by project