# mybatis org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-mybatis

I am using Spring MVC with Spring-Mybatis for performing basic CRUD operations using Annotations(`@Insert`, `@Select` etc) and getting this following exception

`org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found):`

Here's a related question, [mybatis spring mvc application, getting Invalid bound statement (not found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20427210/mybatis-spring-mvc-application-getting-invalid-bound-statement-not-found) but that doesn't solve my problem as it uses XML(`UserMapper.xml`) mapping for queries where I use java interfaces(`UserMapper.java`) with Annotations.

**Exception stacktrace:**

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): com.spring.mybatisdemo.mappers.UserMapper.selectNationality
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.__doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1060)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:509)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:540)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): com.spring.mybatisdemo.mappers.UserMapper.selectNationality
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod$SqlCommand.<init>(MapperMethod.java:196)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.<init>(MapperMethod.java:44)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.cachedMapperMethod(MapperProxy.java:59)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:52)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy41.selectNationality(Unknown Source)
    at com.spring.mybatisdemo.service.UserServiceImpl.selectNationalityById(UserServiceImpl.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.fY.invoke(JRebel:1114)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43.selectNationalityById(Unknown Source)
    at com.spring.mybatisdemo.controller.UserController.getUsers(UserController.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
```

**springConfig.xml**

```
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="com.spring.mybatisdemo.model"/>
  <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:com/spring/mybatis/mappers/*.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
  <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
  <property name="basePackage" value="com.spring.mybatisdemo.mappers" />
</bean>
```

**Nationality** POJO class,

```
public class Nationality {  
  private Long nationalityId;
  private String name;

  //ignoring getters and setters
}
```

I'm using annotation for the queries and below is my relevant code from UserMapper.java interface,

```
@Select("SELECT nationalityId, name FROM nationality where nationalityId = #{nationalityId} ")
public Nationality selectNationality(Long nationalityId);
```

Calling the above method like,

```
Nationality nationality = userService.selectNationalityById(new Long("1"));
```

And in `UserServiceImpl.java` I have injected the UserMapper bean and use it like,

```
userMapper.selectNationality(nationalityId);
```

The same query I used for selecting the `teamById` work fine,

```
userMapper.getTeamById(teamId)
```

and

```
@Select("SELECT teamId, name FROM TEAM WHERE teamId = #{teamId}")
public Team getTeamById(Long teamId);
```

and the corresponding teamById query in console,

```
[artifact:mvn] 2015-11-02 18:51:20 DEBUG SpringManagedTransaction:54 - JDBC Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@1e846b60] will be managed by Spring
[artifact:mvn] 2015-11-02 18:51:20 DEBUG getTeamById:54 - ==>  Preparing: SELECT teamId, name FROM TEAM WHERE teamId = ? 
[artifact:mvn] 2015-11-02 18:51:20 DEBUG getTeamById:54 - ==> Parameters: 4(Long)
[artifact:mvn] 2015-11-02 18:51:20 DEBUG getTeamById:54 - <==      Total: 1
```

I can't get why only the Nationality has this problem while the same method for Team class works fine. What could be the problem in my code for fetching the Nationality data?

Answer (score 9):

I once made a similar mistake which turned out that the directories were incorrect.
If the UserMapper's namespace is `com.mybatisdemo.mappers.UserMapper`, make sure mapper-locations is `src/resources/com/mybatisdemo/mappers/`.
 
Sometimes we might create a directory named `com.mybatisdemo.mappers`, then its location turns out to be `src/resources/com.mybatisdemo.mappers` which is wrong.

Comment: Daymn, you saved my time, that was my case. Thank you. I've just mistakenly added package-like folder, but had to create a folder structure instead in junit tests... :facepalm: and i have fold directories structure so I didnt see that this is just a folder, not folded dirs.