# Mybatis Invalid bound statement (not found)

Tags: java, maven, mybatis

environments: maven ,spring 4.2.4-RELEASE , 2 modules: zscb-server zscb-common ,and zscb-server dependent on zscb-common

my web.xml core code:

```
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.iidooo.core.listener.RoleResourceInitListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

i have a init listener in my module zscb-common:

RoleResourceInitListener core code:

```
 public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        try {
            ServletContext sc = arg0.getServletContext();
            SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory = (SqlSessionFactory) SpringUtil.getBean(sc, "sqlSessionFactory");

            SqlSession sqlSession = sqlSessionFactory.openSession(true);
            SecurityRoleMapper roleMapper = sqlSession.getMapper(SecurityRoleMapper.class);
            List<SecurityRole> roleList = roleMapper.selectAll();

            // key: roleID value:List<SecurityResource>
            Map<Integer, List<SecurityResource>> roleResourceMap = new HashMap<Integer, List<SecurityResource>>();
            for (SecurityRole item : roleList) {
                roleResourceMap.put(item.getRoleID(), item.getResourceList());
            }
            sc.setAttribute(ServletConstant.ROLE_RESOURCE_MAP, roleResourceMap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.fatal(e);
        }
    }
```

my applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
        <property name="basePackage" value="com.iidooo.core.mapper com.edo.zscb.mapper" />
        <property name="sqlSessionFactoryBeanName" value="sqlSessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
```

i have checked my mapper.xml's namepsace:

```
<mapper namespace="com.iidooo.core.mapper.SecurityRoleMapper">
```

and when i run tomcat, error occured

```
Mybatis Invalid bound statement (not found)
```

who can save me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mybatis spring mvc application, getting Invalid bound statement (not found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20427210/mybatis-spring-mvc-application-getting-invalid-bound-statement-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

First result when googling `MapperScannerConfigurer`  leads to the [documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/spring/apidocs/reference/org/mybatis/spring/mapper/MapperScannerConfigurer.html) stating:

> The basePackage property can contain more than one package name,
>   separated by **either commas or semicolons**.

while your packages are separated by a space.

Answer (score 0):

In Mybatis if you add a mapper in a way like `getMapper(YourMapper.class)` or `addMapper(YourMapper.class)`, it is necessary to leave the relative `YourMapper.xml` inside the same source package.

In maven it is also necessary to include the xml file(s) as resources and they must be in same place of the generated `.class` file.

So it would be something like this inside the `<build>` section of your `pom.xml` file:

```
   <build>
        ...
        <resources>
           <resource>
              <filtering>false</filtering>
              <directory>src</directory>
              <includes>
                <include>**/package_path/to/your/*.xml</include>
              </includes>
           </resource>
        </resources>
       ...
   </build>
```

With this configuration maven will leave .xml files in the same place as you have in your source tree.