# idea Invalid bound statement (not found)

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, mybatis

i am using idea 2021, i have a spring boot project with maven and mybatis.

i often encounter this problem:

once I modify the mybatis sql xml file(e.g. `booking.xml`), then I redeploy this project(I have to redeploy such that make the modification under `src/main/resource` effect).

After that, error `Invalid bound statement (not found): xxx` throw if i access the sql which in the modification sql xml file(e.g. I modified content of `updateBooking`, it will say `invalid bound statment(not found): selectBooking`). I am pretty sure the bound statement is exist in this sql xml file and all works before modifying.

I checked the `target` of this idea project and found that there is no `booking.xml` file, it seems that this sql xml file is deleted from `target` after I modified it and redeploy.

In order to solve it, I need to run `mvn clean package` for this project then redeploy it.

it seems that this happen in idea, i didn't encounter it in eclipse before.

How can i fix this problem permanently?

[image]

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/56647432/8203759 help?

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov thanks for your reply, but it's not the same as mine.

Comment: Maybe the automatic compilation/build settings in Idea are a bit off. Should pick all resources automatically. If the Maven build works well, then it's something in the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

1. I use the following configuration every time I have this problem.

   ```xml
    <resources>
               <resource>
                   <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                   <includes>
                       <include>**/*.xml</include>
   ....
                   </includes>
               </resource>
           </resources>
   ```
2. `mvn clean package`.
3. restart IDEA.